# Bootstrap 3 Datepicker v4 - jquery.noConflict() mode

Tags: eonasdan-datetimepicker

Can I somehow specify the jQuery variable to use?

I have already jQuery version 1.7.x loaded on startup and Datepicker needs version 1.9.x. I have no chance of changing the original $ variable so I loaded jQuery 3.x in no conflict mode to _$. Is there any way to tell Datepicker to use that instead of $?